# SweetAlert2 syntax error on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, sweetalert2

I'm using the exactly code of [SweetAlert2 examples page](https://sweetalert2.github.io/):

```
swal({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    swal(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  }
})
```

Works fine on Firefox and Chrome, but Internet Explorer shows `SCRIPT1002: Syntax Error` and not run the script...IE flag this portion as syntax error:

```
}).then((result) => {
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`(result) => {}` is an arrow function which is completely unsupported in IE. To fix this you'll have to use a traditional anonymous function:

```
swal({
  // options...
}).then(function(result) {
  if (result.value) {
    swal('Deleted!', 'Your file has been deleted.', 'success');
  }
});
```

Comment: Ooh really... IE surprised me again haha... Works fine, thanks =D

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Searching for an hour, thought this was a promise problem. Such an easy fix, thanks!

Comment: IE did it again!

Answer (score 4):

IE11 does not support some modern ES6 features like [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

To fix it, you should either compile your code with Babel, or use a [Promise-polyfill](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@7.1.0/dist/promise.min.js) with the traditional `function` syntax:

```
swal(...)
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.value)
  })
```

Read more about SweetAlert2 usage: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2#usage

Answer (score 0):

Aditionally to anonymous functions, to have swal fully functional in IE, its necessary add and script tag

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/core.js"></script>
```

As seen in https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2#1-ie-support

Answer (score 0):

To make showLoading() work in IE11 you need to use the [promise shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill) and an anonymous function...

```
Swal.fire({
    title: "Saving",
    text: "Please wait...",
    onBeforeOpen: function() {
        Swal.showLoading();
    }
});
```